# LINKEDIN api : Invalid file name while uploading the photo url

Tags: postman, linkedin-api

For posting multiple photos, I need to upload the photos with the following api

```
https://api.linkedin.com/media/upload
```

[image]

passing image through url. But getting the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As it accepts multipart/form-data, Need to change the type to file.